# How to use refresh token to get new access token in Excel add-in using OfficeJS

Tags: office-js

We are using Office js helpers to achieve login screen with OAUTH identity server(3rd-Party OAuth Implicit Provider) and we were able to get id token and access token successfully.
Based on our requirement we have to use refresh token to get new access token once it is expired within specified duration. Can you please help on achieving this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The office-js-helpers library is deprecated. You can still use it, but Microsoft doesn't support it. For code that shows the use of the OAuth 2.0 Implicit Flow (which is what the office-js-helpers library uses) in an add-in, we now point people to [Office Add-in Microsoft Graph React](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/master/Samples/auth/Office-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-React). However, [this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111753/is-it-possible-to-use-msal-js-to-get-refresh-token) indicates that you can't use refresh tokens with the Implicit Flow. It suggests a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your information Rick. Also can you please confirm that whether  can it be used our 3rd-Party OAuth Implicit Provider (own identity server) in our application instead of AAD?

Comment: Yes. If your own server supports Implicit Flow, then you can use the Implicit Flow in an add-in.

Comment: Ok. atlast one more clarification that since office-js-helpers library is deprecated, do we need to replace this office-js-helpers implementation with Microsoft Graph React flow like msal.js login popup implementation or still we can go with helpers library?

Comment: You can still use office-js-helpers. But it is no longer being maintained and there will be no more bug fixes.